# Ionic 2 angular-moment-timezone - Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm not exactly sure what I did, but I installed `angular-moment-timezone` in my Ionic project today, got it working, could run `ionic serve` just fine, but then I decided to remove my `node_modules` folder. Once I did that, I ran `npm i` and once that all finished, anytime I try to run `ionic serve`, I get these errors:

```
Typescript Error

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz'.
node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/index.d.ts

undefined
undefined

Typescript Error

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz'.
node_modules/angular-moment-timezone/node_modules/@types/moment-timezone/index.d.ts

undefined
undefined
```

I have no idea what I did wrong and I haven't found anything that can help so far. Has anyone else had this same issue?

Comment: post your code on how you are using in code

Comment: It sounds like you have a dependency on `@types/moment-timezone` in your `package.json` and the semver for that dependency differs from - and does not match - the dependency that `ngular-moment-timezone` has on `@types/moment-timezone`.

Comment: Have you figured out the solution ? @steve-star

Answer (score 6):

We have the `@types/moment-timezone` in our dependency which causes the error.

> cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'tz' moment-timezone

Since moment-timezone version `0.5.30`, d.ts files will be inside moment-timezone. You can save remove it

> `npm uninstall @types/moment-timezone`